# Is a utility power that has the encounter keyword considered an "encounter power"?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Powers are divided into `At-Will`, `Encounter`, `Utility`, and `Daily` powers, which you gain at different levels.

At 12th level, my character (a blood mage) now has:

> **`Soul Burn`** Blood Mage Utility 12 (Daily Arcane)
>   Minor Action / Personal
>   **Effect**: You spend a healing surge. Instead of regaining hit 
>   points, you regain one encounter power you have already 
>   used.

Does this apply to Utility powers that have the `Encounter` keyword? Or does it only apply to the Encounter powers gained at levels 1, 3, 7, etc.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anything with the `encounter` usage type is valid for Soul Burn.

I think you are confusing a couple things which Wizards didn't do a very good job of explaining.

Powers are only divided into two types:

- **Attack**: Powers which are used to damage or hinder others (mostly)
- **Utility**: Everything else

Either of those types can have one of the three usage types that we are all familiar with:

- **At-Will**
- **Encounter**
- **Daily**

This is all defined on pp89-91 of the *Rules Compendium* and p54 of the *Player's Handbook*.

Having defined all this the books then go around and refer to `Encounter Powers` and `Daily Powers` when what they really mean is `Encounter Usage Type`, etc.  Usage Type wasn't strictly defined in the Player's Handbook so I guess they went with the shortened version.